# Extract a property value from a text file

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

I have a log file which contains lines like the following one:

```
Internal (reserved=1728469KB, committed=1728469KB)
```

I'd need to extract the value contained in "committed", so 1728469
I'm trying to use awk for that

```
cat file.txt | awk '{print $4}'
```

However that produces:

```
committed=1728469KB)
```

This is still incomplete and would need still some work. Is there a simpler solution to do that instead?
Thanks

Comment: `awk -F= '{sub(/[)]/,"",$3); print $3}` might help. Good luck

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3070141/how-do-i-use-grep-to-extract-a-specific-field-value-from-lines , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080988/how-to-extract-string-following-a-pattern-with-grep-regex-or-perl

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sed is better at simple matching tasks:

```
sed -n 's/.*committed=\([0-9]*\).*/\1/p' input_file
```

Answer (score 6):

Could you please try following, using `match` function of `awk`.

```
awk 'match($0,/committed=[0-9]+/){print substr($0,RSTART+10,RLENGTH-10)}' Input_file
```

With GNU `grep` using `\K` option of it:

```
grep -oP '.*committed=\K[0-9]*' Input_file
```

Output will be `1728469` in both above solutions.

***1st solution explanation:***

```
awk '                                      ##Starting awk program from here.
match($0,/committed=[0-9]+/){              ##Using match function to match from committed= till digits in current line.
  print substr($0,RSTART+10,RLENGTH-10)    ##Printing sub string from RSTART+10 to RLENGTH-10 in current line.
}
' Input_file                               ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Answer (score 5):

```
$ awk -F'[=)]' '{print $3}' file
1728469KB
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
str="Internal (reserved=1728469KB, committed=1728469KB)"
echo $str | awk '{print $3}' | cut -d "=" -f2 | rev | cut -c4- | rev
```